# my links to my external .css fail in aptana but work on the live web server; how can i fix this?

Tags: css, path, hyperlink, external

my problem i think is simply to do with my .css paths.

for example my file structure is as so:

(root folder) mysite:

```
-index.htm

-styles.css
```

---

within my index.htm code, i link to my style sheets with the following code:

**/styles.css**

Now, changing the pathway is not a solution, i need to keep it as above with the **"/"** to point it to the root first.  As the webstie works perfectly online this way.

Is there anyway i can get the site to display my styles locally, some kind of setting?
I have messed for hours reading through the forums here, and playing with setting the root.

i just dont get why once i set the correct root it messes up the path to the style sheets. I am starting to think it is impossible to link a .css file with "/" in Aptana.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the / from "/styles.css" then index.html will load it correctly both locally and on your website.

You also might want to look into the html base tag:
  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

This would allow your pages to always point to the css file that is live on the website.

You say that "changing the pathway is not a solution", please explain?  A live example would be good too.

Comment: thankyou for the quick reply, your right about removing the "/" will work on both. However, on the live server, the .index file at the end of each day is copied and moved to another folder within the site "archive". When moved across the "/styles.css" within that moved file still works! if i removed the "/" the linkage would fail. This is the reason for not changing the linkage pathway.  I will take a look at base tag, thankyou for the link

Comment: sadly I cant use <base> as i have other links on the page which it would affect.

Comment: Apologies, I don't have direct experience with Aptana.

Normally when developing websites though, one would run a local web server such as Apache.  This allows developers to use paths such as `/styles.css` when accessing the local web server as well as on the live website. I believe this is supported by Aptana.

Accessing the locally running web server would be something like `http://127.0.0.1/index.html`

That is about all I can offer.

Good luck!

Comment: thankyou for your time and help Jonathan, i will look into setting up Apache.  In the meantime if anyone else knows if it is even possible to fix my problem with aptana please feel free to chime in.